# SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to update the ABS library in my project.

So I deleted the old one and added the latest version.

I get the following error :

> SherlockActivity cannot be resolved to a type

on one of the very first lines:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockActivity {
(...)
```

Comment: During compilation or runtime?

Comment: Well, Eclipse just underlines it with red and forbids me to launch the app

Comment: Try cleaning the Sherlock library, and make sure it's included in your project. Try writing `import com.` and see if it auto-completes Sherlock's package for you. (Also, this is a compile-time error, for reference.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed my problem by updating eclipse and android SDK.